# Select the most dissimilar individual using cluster analysis

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I want to cluster my data to say 5 clusters, then we need to select 50 individuals with most dissimilar relationship from all the data. That means if cluster one contains 100, two contains 200, three contains 400, four contains 200, and five 100, I have  to select 5 from the first cluster + 10 from the second cluster + 20 from the third + 10 from the fourth + 5 from the fifth.

Data example:

```
     mydata<-matrix(nrow=100,ncol=10,rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

What I did till now is clustering the data and rank the individuals within each cluster, then export it to excel and go from there … 
That has become became a problem since my data has became really big.

I will appreciate any help or suggestion on how to apply the previous in R
.

Comment: Do you need help w/ the R *commands* to get this done, or w/ *understanding* the process that would be used? This sounds to me like a conceptual question about statistics, rather than a programming question about R. If so, this Q would be better migrated to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) (ie, stats.SE).

Comment: Statistically it is very clear to me ---- I need help with how to do it in R

Comment: What R code do you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

I´m not sure if it is exactly what you are searching, but maybe it helps:

```
mydata<-matrix(nrow=100, ncol=10, rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1))
rownames(mydata) <- paste0("id", 1:100) # some id for identification


# cluster objects and calculate dissimilarity matrix
cl <- cutree(hclust(
  sim <- dist(mydata, diag = TRUE, upper=TRUE)), 5) 

# combine results, take sum to aggregate dissimilarity
res <- data.frame(id=rownames(mydata),
                  cluster=cl, dis_sim=rowSums(as.matrix(sim)))
# order, lowest overall dissimilarity will be first
res <- res[order(res$dis_sim), ] 


# split object
reslist <- split(res, f=res$cluster)


## takes first three items with highest overall dissim.
lapply(reslist, tail, n=3) 

## returns id´s with highest overall dissimilarity, top 20% 
lapply(reslist, function(x, p) tail(x, round(nrow(x)*p)), p=0.2)
```

Comment: Dear Holzben it really helped thank you--- one more thing within clusters, how to pick the individuals that are closest to the cluster centroid? --- again thank you so much for your nice codes and response

Answer (score 1):

regarding you comment, find the code below:

pleas note that the code can be improved in terms of beauty and efficiency.
Further I used a second answer, because otherwise it would be to messy.

```
# calculation of centroits based on:
# https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/105328.html
cl <- hclust(dist(mydata, diag = TRUE, upper=TRUE))
cent <- tapply(mydata, 
        list(rep(cutree(cl, 5), ncol(mydata)), col(mydata)), mean)
dimnames(cent) <- list(NULL, dimnames(mydata)[[2]])


# add up cluster number and data and split by cluster
newdf <- data.frame(data=mydata, cluster=cutree(cl, k=5))
newdfl <- split(newdf, f=newdf$cluster)

# add centroids and drop cluster info
totaldf <- lapply(1:5, 
           function(i, li, cen) rbind(cen[i, ], li[[i]][ , -11]),
                                li=newdfl, cen=cent)


# calculate new distance to centroits and sort them
dist_to_cent <- lapply(totaldf, function(x)
                   sort(as.matrix(dist(x, diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))[1, ]))
dist_to_cent
```

for calculation of centroids out of `hclust` see [R-Mailinglist](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/105328.html)

Comment: thank you for your time ---- based on the data example i thought it might be better to use kmeans and cluster the data to 50 clusters ( because i want to select 50 individuals ) --- and then select one individual/ cluster with the closest distance to the center of the cluster --- what do you think?  sorry for troubling you with that many questions.

Comment: If you are interested in analyzing centroits kmeans is clearly a more natural choice than hierarchical clustering... In my example I started with hierarchical clustering, therefore I also did it in the second example. Your suggestion sound good, but I´m not sure what your overall goal is....